# How do I get rid of java.lang.NumberFormatException error

Tags: java

This code takes two txt files, reads them puts them in 2d arrays and should check if the numbers in the files are magic squares but it keeps returning NumberFormatException error. I'm new to java so if anyone could help me that would be great. I'm pretty sure the problem come from the txt file being string and the 2d array needing to be in int form. But how and where do I make that conversion on my code?

this is what i have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ms {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filename1 = "magicSquaresData.txt", filename2 = "magicSquaresData.txt";

        int nos[][] = null;
        nos = getArray(filename1);

        boolean b = isMagicSquare(nos);
        printArray(nos);
        if (b) {
            System.out.println("It is a magic Square");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is not a magic Square");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        nos = getArray(filename2);

        b = isMagicSquare(nos);
        printArray(nos);

        if (b) {
            System.out.println("It is a magic Square");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is not a magic Square");
        }
    }

    private static int[][] getArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String line;
        int nos[][] = null;
        int size = 0, rows = 0;
        Scanner sc = null;

        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                if (!sc.nextLine().isEmpty())
                    size++;
            }
            sc.close();
            nos = new int[size][size];
            sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                line = sc.nextLine();
                if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                    String arr[] = line.split("\t");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        nos[rows][i] = Integer.valueOf(arr[i]);
                    }
                    rows++;
                }
            }
            sc.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return nos;
    }

    private static void printArray(int[][] nos){
        for(int i = 0; i<nos[0].length;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nos[0].length; j++){
            System.out.printf("%-3d",nos[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();


        }
    }

    private static boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] square) {
        boolean bool = true;
        int order = square.length;
        int[] sumRow = new int[order];
        int[] sumCol = new int[order];
        int[] sumDiag = new int[2];
        Arrays.fill(sumRow, 0);
        Arrays.fill(sumCol, 0);
        Arrays.fill(sumDiag, 0);

        for (int row = 0; row < order; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < order; col++) {
                sumRow[row] += square[row][col];
            }
        }

        for (int col = 0; col < order; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
                sumCol[col] += square[row][col];
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
            sumDiag[0] += square[row][row];
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
            sumDiag[1] += square[row][order - 1 - row];
        }

        bool = true;
        int sum = sumRow[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < order; i++) {
            bool = bool && (sum == sumRow[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
            bool = bool && (sum == sumCol[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            bool = bool && (sum == sumDiag[i]);
        }
        return bool;

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `arr[i]`? Are you always getting numbers?

Comment: _how and where do I make that conversion on my code?_ - Um, `Integer.valueOf()`? And that line is probably printed in the exception you are seeing...

Comment: Q: Did you resolve the problem? Q: Did you try "troubleshooting tip" I suggested [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74310473/421195), and did it tell you WHERE the error was occurring ... and WHY? Q: What did you wind up doing?

Answer (score -1):

SUGGESTION:

Substitute `nos[rows][i] = Integer.valueOf(arr[i]);` for a custom method that will tell you WHERE the error is occurring.

EXAMPLE:

```
public static Integer tryParse(String text, int row, int i) {
  try {
    return Integer.parseInt(text);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: row=" + row + ", i=" + i + ", text=" + text);
    return null;
  }
}
```

CAVEAT: This is for helping you troubleshoot ONLY.  You definitely wouldn't want to release this in "production code" ;)

Comment: Don't return `null`, do `throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: row=" + row + ", i=" + i + ", text=" + text, e);`

Comment: My suggestion was for troubleshooting purposes ONLY.  In this case, rethrowing the exception might be a good idea - or might be overkill.  It depends.  You'll note, too, the OP's error handling in getArray() is problematic.  For a "real program" - he'd want to structure where exceptions are thrown, where they're caught, and how they're handled differently.  Holistically. But for this "toy program", it absolutely doesn't matter.  I stand by my original suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

### What is the [*NumberFormatException*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)?

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

Offtopic:
A thing that i can notice is that both filesnames have the same name. So you will verify the same file 2 times.
`String filename1 = "magicSquaresData.txt", filename2 = "magicSquaresData.txt";`

I checked your program and you error appears when you put like this on a file:

```
 1. 5 5
 2. 5 5
```

So the error shows beacause you are trying to parse to int the String "5 5". So your code pick the all line and tries to convert to int and " " it's not an int. And there lives the NumberFormatException error.

### How do to solve it?

The function that we will work on is the one that you pass from file to an array in

```
private static int[][] getArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
```

The of the function is after we read the file.
As you said, you are leading with a 2d array so to insert all the numbers we need to have loops for each dimension on the array. 
So we will start from there.
I will use a while beacause we are dealing with a string and it's easier to verify the text that its left on the line. 
Will add a new int variable that starts in 0 to pass in every column of a line to use with the while loop. And with this we got this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    while(!"".equals(line)){
        whileIterator++;
    }
    whileIterator = 0;
}
```

Next setep, we will divide in 2 behaviors because we will substring the String that has in the line, and will work differently when it's the last number that we are verifying:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    while(!"".equals(line)){
        if(whileIterator + 1 == size){//If its the last iteration that we need in a line
        }else{//All other iterations
             whileIterator++;
        }
    whileIterator = 0;}
```

To finalize let's add the new logic to insert in *nos* array. So lets pick all line for example 2 7 6 and we want to add the number 2, so lets do that. You just need to substring(int startIndex, int finalIndex) the line and add to the *nos* array. After that let remove the number and the space ("2 ") from the line that we are veryfying.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    while(!"".equals(line)){
        if(whileIterator + 1 == size){//If its the last iteration that we need
            nos[rows][whileIterator] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0));//Add to array
            line = "";//To not pass the while verification
        }else{//All other iterations
            nos[rows][whileIterator] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" ")));//Add to array
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") + 1);//remove the number we added behind
        }
        whileIterator++;
    }
    whileIterator = 0;}
```

And here you go, that how you add the numbers to an array and don't get the error.
If you need some further explanation just ask. Hope it helps :)